# Hide parentNode based on grandChild innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, innerhtml

I need to hide an entire row  based on childNodes innerHTML. Basically in my form I have a Status Dropdown menu but hiding that on it's own doesn't get ride of the row. How would I set the display of  to none?

[image]

Comment: `$("nobr").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childeNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Status"; }).closest("tr").hide()`. This finds all `<nobr>` elements, gets their first child node (which in the example, is a text node with whitespace and then "Status"), and checks that the value is "Status". Of course, you can narrow *which* `<nobr>` elements are targeted at first.

Comment: I ran this as is and got error: Cannot read property 0 of undefined

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled - it's `childNodes`, not `childeNodes`

Comment: Oh wow I saw that and thought it was spelt weird but didn't think it was an error. KK ill try again, thanks. EDIT: Worked, Thanks! You said I could narrow it down a bit, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something like:

```
$("nobr").filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Status";
}).closest("tr").hide();
```

This finds **all** `<nobr>` elements on the page, gets their first child node (which in the example, is a text node with whitespace and text like "Status"), and checks that its text is "Status".

This would definitely need updated if the order of elements in the `<nobr>` isn't what the example shows, or differs across rows, or anything else, because this is a very specific search.

Of course, you can narrow which `<nobr>` elements are targeted at first. For example, if the HTML you wanted to target was only within a table, you could first find the table and then look at the `<nobr>` elements within:

```
$("#table_id").find("nobr").filter(func...
```